# IAR ARM compiler has strange assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I am currently developing a project with an ARM CM0+ core and using IAR compiler. When i checked the assembly output of the compiler i found some strange instructions like "STRDEQ" "EORPL" etc. These instructions are not documented in ARM documentation. Is there any one understand this behaviour.

Thanks all.

Comment: See section 3.2 _"The condition field"_ of the ARM DDI 0100E document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original ARM Instruction Set allows most instructions to be conditional. This is mainly used for cases like:

```
if(c == x)
  c = 0
```

This will be compiled to something like this:

```
cmp   r0, r1
moveq r0, #0
```

Here the actual opcode is mov and it has a condition attached to it, so it only executes when the comparison before it has set the Z-Flag.

This saves a branch instruction. The idea behind that stems in the fact that branches were a quite expensive operation in the past. Today we've got better branch predictors and speculative execution, which makes these kind of optimization less efficient. Newer ISAs (Thumb1/2 and AArch64) from ARM do not support the conditional execution for most of the instructions anymore. The main-reasons are better branch-prediction and the very high cost in opcode-space. The condition has to be encoded inside the opcode, which takes away 4-bits, which is quite a lot. Thumb and Thumb2 had a pseudo instruction IT (and variants with different amounts of T(hen) and E(lse) appended to it), which allows to make the instructions AFTER it conditional.

Nonetheless AFAIK the Cortex M0+ does not support the ARM-ISA, nor the IT-instructions from Thumb. So maybe your compiler is set to a wrong target.